# Difficult SELECT statement with only two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, select

I have an SQL Server table structured as follows :

```
Table name : calendar.
```

Columns :

```
Calendar Date (smalldatetime)
Working Day (bit)
```

Calendar date has all dates, structured in the format yyyy-mm-dd. Working day means that I have work if it is a 1, and if it is a weekend or a holiday it is marked as a 0 :).

Example of what I want to retrieve :

```
Date   NumWorkingDaysInMonthSoFar
------------------------------------
2013-06-01    0 --Due to this being marked a 0 as above (Saturday)
2013-06-02    0 --Due to this being marked a 0 as above (Sunday) -- All 3 of these dates marked as 0
2013-06-03    1 --Due to this being marked a 0 as above (Bank Holiday)
2013-06-04    1
2013-06-05    2
2013-06-06    3
```

Except I would like the query to work for ALL dates in the calendar - so if I ran it today, it would retrieve the number of working days in the month containing all of the calendar dates in my table above.

All of the information is there, but I am just not sure how to write a query like this or even where to begin, but I think I have gotten the barebones of it below :

```
SELECT Sum(Working Day)
       WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, CalendarDate)) between
              GETDATE() and START_OF_MONTH
       GROUP BY (Not a clue)
```

Comment: Changed the question slightly; I now want to retrieve the full dataset for all dates. Not just the current date. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 has direct support for cumulative sums.  For earlier versions, you need to do something like a fancy join or correlated subquery.  I prefer the latter, because I think it is easier to read:

```
select c.[date],
       (select sum(cast(WorkingDay as int))
        from calendar c2
        where year(c.[date]) = year(c2.[date]) and
              month(c.[date]) = month(c2.[date]) and
              c2.[date] <= c.[date]
       ) as NumWorkingDaysInMonth
from calendar c
```

In SQL Server 2012, you would just do:

```
select c.[date],
       sum(cast(WorkingDay as int)) over (partition by year(c.[date], month[c.date])
                                          order by c.[date]
                                         ) as NumWorkingDaysInMonth
from calendar c
```

Comment: I have no idea how people get to be so good at SQL. Two further questions if you don't mind - 1. How did you get so good? 2. How could I adapt this code to only retrieve results after 2013-01-01? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SimonKiely . . . If you are interested in SQL and/or data analysis, you should check out my books on Amazon.  To only retrieve specific results, add a `where` clause to the outer `select`.

Comment: You have made a sale! Thank you :)